# how to pass variable in http in angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular9

> ''' how will i add fromDateTime and toDateTime as parameters to be
> passed in this link.'''

```
 export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
      const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
      protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=2019-11-01,toDateTime=2019-12-01', ['CallRecords.Read.All','CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All','CallRecords.Read.All']);
    
      return {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        protectedResourceMap
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of string interpolation:

```js
let queryUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=${fromDatetimeVariable},toDateTime=${toDatetimeVariable}`
```

Note that the string is surrounded in backticks (**`**) not in quotes (**'**)

Comment: core.mjs:6495 ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=2019-11-01,toDateTime=2019-12-01/: Unterminated group
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)

Comment: but i am getting this error :(